# Is there any way to check whether the Hadoop file is already opened for write?

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop2

Multiple Java instances are running on my machine and I want to check whether the Hadoop file is already opened in write (`fs.create(file) or fs.append(file)`) mode in any of the instances.
I Tried in `FileStatus` of the Hadoop file, not found anything.
 **Is there any way to check whether the Hadoop file is already opened for write?**

One way is to try to create/append a file again and catch the exception, but I have thousands of files and don't want to try every file. Also, if create/append is a success, then I have to close the file and lastModifiedTime will also get changed. I don't want to modify the FileStatus of a Hadoop file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DistributedFileSystem` provides the method `isFileClosed(path)` to check whether the file is opened for write.

```
try {
    DistributedFileSystem dfs = new DistributedFileSystem();
    Path path = new Path("/path/to/hadoop/file");
    FileSystem fs = path.getFileSystem(conf);
    dfs.initialize(fs.getUri(),conf);

    if (dfs.exists(path) && !dfs.isFileClosed(path)) {
        System.out.println("File " + path +" already opened in write mode");
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: life saver! I tried many different solutions, but only this one worked